# How to test image upload API using postman?

Tags: postman, apiclient

I have an Image Uploading API which I call from android and Its working fine.Now I want to test same API using Postman.

Someone please guide me to test this API on Postman. What parameters I need to set in Postman to test this API.

I have tried to test this API using following parameters in post man but till now not able to succeed. I tried to attach image in postman parameter and converted image to binary then add that binary in postman parameter but API is giving unsuccessful response.

```
--16cbe71399a
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="binaryFile"; filename="ec6152a8a12b4782b1c4bcc95cc98eeb"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
binaryFile:{local path of image}
--16cbe71399a--
```

The working android code is as follows:

API: `http://testing/api/editImage/`

Header:

```
("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);<br>
("Authorization", "bearer "+preference.getFileAPIAuthenticationToken())<br>
```

Body:

```
writer.append("--" + boundary).append(CRLF);
writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"binaryFile\"; filename=\"" + ugid + "\"").append(CRLF);
writer.append("Content-Type: " + URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(binaryFile.getName())).append(CRLF);
writer.append("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary").append(CRLF);
writer.append(CRLF);
// file write in binary
writer.append(CRLF);
writer.append("--" + boundary+ "--").append(CRLF);
```

Comment: In postman you can change the type of the form-data key to file input instead of text, have you tried this option?